# XSLT not copying the xmlns in my xml

Tags: xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<c:configuration xmlns:c="urn:schemas-med-sadfens-com:config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-med-sadfens-com:config D:\config.xsd">
<c:component c:name="FC1PLAZACS1-DEV [Central Server]" c:keywords="Server" c:helpriid="11f7b87d-52ae-434b-8ace-4ffb4ecbe080">
        <c:propertyelement c:name="System manufacturer" c:value="select Manufacturer from Win32_ComputerSystem" c:type="Wmi" xmlns:c="urn:schemas-med-siemens-com:config" />
        <c:propertyelement c:name="System model" c:value="select Model from Win32_ComputerSystem" c:type="Wmi" xmlns:c="urn:schemas-med-siemens-com:config"/>
</c:component>
</c:configuration>
```

In the above xml i want everything as it is but my xsl is not copying it

i.e it is not able to copy the element  xmlns:c="urn:schemas-med-siemens-com:config"  from the

```
<c:propertyelement c:name="System manufacturer" c:value="select Manufacturer from Win32_ComputerSystem" c:type="Wmi" xmlns:c="urn:schemas-med-siemens-com:config" />
```

Please find my XSl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:c="urn:schemas-med-siemens-com:config" >

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

please let me know the answer as soon as u people can

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using?  I've just tested this with `xsltproc` and it _does_ copy the namespace declarations correctly.

Comment: I am able to copy it with Saxon6.5.5

Answer (score 0):

I use something similar to the following to migrate nodes to a new namespace, YMMV:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
  xmlns:c="urn:schemas-med-siemens-com:config" >
  <xsl:param
     name="new-ns"
     select="'http://my.new.ns'"
     />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{$new-ns}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```